# Opening a Business in the UK

Tags: working-visas, business

I am South African and own a Laser Clinic in South Africa .My Mom is a British Citizen and my daughter who is half Dutch half South African also attends university and resides in the UK.
I am interested in opening up my Laser Beauty Clinic in the UK.
I am married to a British citizen however we have been residing in South Africa.

What type of visa do I need to apply for in order to set up and operate my Business in the UK?

Kind regards,
Nikki

Comment: Do you intend to move to the UK?  Will you be moving there with your spouse?

Comment: A ‘Representative of an Overseas Business’ visa might serve? https://www.gov.uk/representative-overseas-business

Comment: @Traveller *If you are coming to the UK as a sole representative you must: [...] hold a senior position within the company (**but not be a major shareholder**) and have full authority to make decisions on its behalf*